# A spring request give me only null

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

The thing is, I'm doing a web-based class work to manage a warehouse with spring and Thymeleaf. The problem is that when putting a form with a dynamic select on the page with Thymeleaf, trying to retrieve the information only gives me a null after another. I would like some genius to help me detect what the exact problem is, since I have been here for about 3 hours and I am not able to get it out. Thanks in advance.

This would be the controller:

```
@Controller
public class MiControlador {

    @Autowired
    IProductoSERVICE productoService;
    
    @Autowired
    IAlmacenSERVICE almacenService;
    
    @Autowired
    IVentaSERVICE ventaService;
    
    ...

    @RequestMapping("/productos")
    public String verProductos(Model model) {
        System.out.println(almacenService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("almacenes", almacenService.findAll());
        return "productos.html";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/productos/selalm")
    public String verProductos(@RequestParam(value = "idAlmacenes", required = false) Integer idAlmacenes, Model model) {
        System.out.println("paso 1");
        System.out.println(idAlmacenes);
        List<Producto> productos = productoService.findByAlm(idAlmacenes);
        System.out.println("Paso 2");
        System.out.println(productos.toString());
        model.addAttribute("productos", productos);
        System.out.println("Paso 3");
        return "productos.html";
    }
```

In the method "verProductos" what I want is to see the products of a specific warehouse.

This would be the Html:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
productos
<form th:action="@{/productos/selalm}" th:field= "*{idAlmacenes}" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" >
      <option th:each= "almacen: ${almacenes}" th:text= "${almacen.nombre}" th:value= "${almacen.idalmacenes}"></option>
    </select>
    <Input type="submit" th:value= "Mostrar">
</form>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Id de producto</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="producto: ${productos}">
         <td th:text="${producto.idproductos}">...</td>
         <td th:text="${producto.nombre}">...</td>
         <td th:text="${producto.precioUnitario}">...</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the beginning, I put a form with a "select" to select the warehouse that I want to inspect, and I send it to the controller "/selalm" with the intention of recovering the data from the BDD and sending it back to "products.html "in order to fill in the table that I have put below.
The problem is that when it comes to printing "Paso 1" and even "Integer idAlmacenes", but the latter prints it to me as null, regardless of what I do.

Finally, this is my "Almacen" class:

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="almacenes")
public class Almacen {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    public int idalmacenes;
    public String nombre;
    public String ubicacion;
    
    public Almacen() {
        super();
    }

    public Almacen(int idalmacenes, String nombre, String ubicacion) {
        super();
        this.idalmacenes = idalmacenes;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return idalmacenes;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.idalmacenes = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getUbicacion() {
        return ubicacion;
    }

    public void setUbicacion(String ubicacion) {
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Almacen [idalmacenes=" + idalmacenes + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", ubicacion=" + ubicacion + "]";
    }
        
}
```

Many thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: I could not exactly understand what is null? Is idAlmacenes or productos null? If idAlmacenes is not null but productos is null then you should also share the Service class.

Comment: Could you provide also exception stacktrace?

Comment: In " public String verProductos(@RequestParam(value = "idAlmacenes"", idAlmacenes must give me the id of the warehouse, but only give me null.

Comment: I have not any error, everything seems to work fine. But the request should give me an id and it only gives me null.

Comment: I dont know if the problem is sending the id from the view (thymeleaf) or recieving it in the controller ( spring requestParam). And can't find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no form backing object. I used the same model to get the selected id.

In the controller,

```
@RequestMapping("/productos")
public String verProductos(Model model) {
    System.out.println(almacenService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("almacenes", almacenService.findAll());
model.addAttribute("selectedOne", new Almacen()); // newly added line
    return "productos.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/productos/selalm")
public String verProductos(@ModelAttribute @NotNull Almacen selectedOne, Model model) {//change in declaration
...
}
```

In the .html file, modified the following lines to use the model.

```
<form th:action="@{/productos/selalm}" th:object="${selectedOne}" method="post">
<select class="form-control"  th:field= "*{idalmacenes}" >
```

Try and feedback.

Comment: In this case throws this error: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'selectedOne' available as request attribute"

Comment: @Eduardo Did you add this line model.addAttribute("selectedOne", new Almacen()); // newly added line

Comment: Oh sorry, i forget it. But i have done it now and then throws this another error: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'idalmacenes' of bean class [es.eduardosarabia.weblogistics.model.Almacen]: Bean property 'idalmacenes' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: I see the method names are not in-line with the variables. Can you change the variable name, as follows and try:

<select class="form-control"  th:field= "*{id}" >

Comment: In this case, i have not the error, but the select in the form is empty. I have changed all the id to idalmacenes too, but the select is still empty. I only get the select working right, without error, putting the th:field in the form and no in the select, i dont know why...

Comment: I made the necessary changes to your code, as posted in the question. It works fine with me. I cannot see what is the current state of your code.

Comment: Ok, getting back the verProductos(Model model) ti the begin and changing in te "option" the th:value="${almacen.idalmacen}" for "${almacen} somethin happend. Now i dont get a null, but only can get 0, and not the real id. Any idea?

Comment: I assume there is no change to Almacen class. Could you post the latest controller and html

Answer (score 0):

the actual state of the controller is this:

```
public class MiControlador {

    @Autowired
    IProductoSERVICE productoService;
    
    @Autowired
    IAlmacenSERVICE almacenService;
    
    @Autowired
    IVentaSERVICE ventaService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String indice() {
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login.html";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/almacenes")
    public String verAlmacenes(Model model) {
        System.out.println(almacenService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("almacenes", almacenService.findAll());
        return "almacenes.html";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/productos")
    public String verProductos(Model model) {
        System.out.println(almacenService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("almacenes", almacenService.findAll()); // newly added line
        model.addAttribute("selectedOne", new Almacen()); // newly added line
        return "productos.html";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/productos/selalm")
    public String verProductos(@ModelAttribute @NotNull Almacen selectedOne, Model model){
        System.out.println("paso 1");
        System.out.println(selectedOne.idalmacenes);
        /*List<Producto> productos = productoService.findByAlm(idalmacenes);
        System.out.println("Paso 2");
        System.out.println(productos.toString());
        model.addAttribute("productos", productos);
        System.out.println("Paso 3");*/
        return "productos.html";
    }
```

And the actual state of the view:

```
public class MiControlador {

    @Autowired
    IProductoSERVICE productoService;
    
    @Autowired
    IAlmacenSERVICE almacenService;
    
    @Autowired
    IVentaSERVICE ventaService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String indice() {
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login.html";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/almacenes")
    public String verAlmacenes(Model model) {
        System.out.println(almacenService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("almacenes", almacenService.findAll());
        return "almacenes.html";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/productos")
    public String verProductos(Model model) {
        System.out.println(almacenService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("almacenes", almacenService.findAll()); // newly added line
        model.addAttribute("selectedOne", new Almacen()); // newly added line
        return "productos.html";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/productos/selalm")
    public String verProductos(@ModelAttribute @NotNull Almacen selectedOne, Model model){
        System.out.println("paso 1");
        System.out.println(selectedOne.idalmacenes);
        /*List<Producto> productos = productoService.findByAlm(idalmacenes);
        System.out.println("Paso 2");
        System.out.println(productos.toString());
        model.addAttribute("productos", productos);
        System.out.println("Paso 3");*/
        return "productos.html";
    }
```

And with this, throw the error:
"An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/productos.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/productos.html]")"
Caused by:
"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'selectedOne' available as request attribute"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it!!!
The problem is i was not giving the name of the form to ther @ModelAttribute. In a lot of forums and spring guides ive readed is not necesar but, it seems that in this specific case, it was necessary. Thnk u @Niyas